# In React, is it possible to memoize a list of components and their internal state?

Tags: reactjs

*[This is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sky-bkczeq?file=/src/Tabs.js) with all of the code that exemplifies the issue I'm having. Sorry, SO doesn't allow for proper React code with TSX, etc.]*

I have some tabs, naturally, whenever I click on each of them, my state changes (namely `selectedTab`) and the body that's being rendered. Each tab item has a body that goes with it, the first tab, in my case, has a component that, if you click, a count is increased. Well, whenever the tab changes, that count gets reset. In fact, it's a full-rerender all around.

The problem with doing a full re-render is that - not only is it inefficient, given how the user's gonna use it, but it also adds fuel to the fire: what if the user inputs something on a tab, then switches to another tab to do something else and then back to the original one? He's just lost what he typed in.

Naturally, this can be solved if we render all of the tabs' content upfront and we just play with `display: none`, and it'd be a good solution, but I'm also trying to learn.

I understand how React re-renders things and why this happens, but is there a way to fix it?

In my case, if you look at `useTabs`, the `content` variable simply looks at the corresponding tab's `component` key and takes outputs that. It's there that, I think, I need to memoize things.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I guess you can't prevent calling your custom hook, this will lead to invariant violation error.

These hooks in the component will be executed on each render -> thus 'resets' your tabs.

You should rely on useEffect dependencies argument to run conditional code to see if values needs to be changed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a beginner, but none of that terminology makes sense to me. Can you provide at least some pseudo-code? The idea here is to see if it's possible to cache a list of components AND their internal state.

Answer (score 0):

as long as your in the same app you could use contextApi,[react context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) otherwise you can use localstorage, [localstorage tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-localstorage-react-hooks/)
or just create this state in the parent component and pass it down as props?